# Sum rows with same Id based on type and exlude where SUM = 0

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have this table **MOVEMENTS**:

```
Id  |  FatherId  |  MovementType |   Quantity   |
=================================================
1   | A         |   IN          |   10          |
2   | A         |   IN          |   5           |
3   | A         |   OUT         |   5           |
4   | B         |   IN          |   10          |
5   | B         |   OUT         |   10          |
6   | C         |   IN          |   5           |
```

I'm trying to get all the FatherId with the SUM of IN - OUT Movments > 0.
So the result would be:

```
FatherId    |   Total   |
=========================
A           |     10    |
C           |     5     |
```

FatherId = B not showing because
SUM(MovementType = IN) - SUM (MovementType = OUT) = 0

I tried with

```
SELECT FatherId,
  (SELECT (
    SUM(CASE WHEN MovementType = 'IN' THEN Quantity ELSE 0 END) -
    SUM(CASE WHEN MovementType = 'OUT' THEN Quantity ELSE 0 END)
  )) AS Total
  FROM MOVEMENTS
  GROUP BY FatherId
  ORDER BY FatherId
```

That gives me the result grouped by FatherId, but I'm not able to filter with Total > 0, and also, I'm unable to put this query in a Subquery like:

```
SELECT * FROM MOVEMENTS WHERE FatherId IN (SELECT ....) OFFSET ... FETCH NEXT ... ROWS ONLY
```

Is this doable without a stored procedure?
Thank you for any help

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Why are you using a subquery?  This should do what you want:

```
SELECT FatherId,
       (SUM(CASE WHEN MovementType = 'IN' THEN Quantity ELSE 0 END) -
        SUM(CASE WHEN MovementType = 'OUT' THEN Quantity ELSE 0 END)
       ) AS Total
FROM MOVEMENTS
GROUP BY FatherId
HAVING (SUM(CASE WHEN MovementType = 'IN' THEN Quantity ELSE 0 END) -
        SUM(CASE WHEN MovementType = 'OUT' THEN Quantity ELSE 0 END)
       ) > 0;
```

You can also simplify the logic to use a single `SUM()`:

```
SELECT FatherId,
       SUM(CASE WHEN MovementType = 'IN' THEN Quantity
                WHEN MovementType = 'OUT' THEN - Quantity
                ELSE 0
           END) AS Total
FROM MOVEMENTS
GROUP BY FatherId
HAVING SUM(CASE WHEN MovementType = 'IN' THEN Quantity
                WHEN MovementType = 'OUT' THEN - Quantity
                ELSE 0
           END) > 0
ORDER BY FatherId;
```

Comment: Thank you! This worked like a charm! How would you page the result? I Tried to put an     `OFFSET 50 ROWS FETCH NEXT 25 ROWS ONLY` in boh the inner and the outer query but gives me an invalid usage.

Comment: Ok solved.. I was missing the `ORDER BY` clause before the `OFFSET` in the inner query. Thank  you!!